# Code completion in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: html, visual-studio

Is there a way to enable code completion in Visual Studio 2015 like we have in VS Code or other code editor? For example, when I type `div.row` and press the `{tab}` key, VS Code will complete the following code:

```
<div class="row">
</div>
```

Is there a way to enable that feature in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want ZenCoding from [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/)

Comment: That's it. Thanks.